# Webdriver Server log

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Would any one please explain how to check webdriver server log? The log we used to see by running selenium server from command line. I am using firefox driver with latest stand alone server. I tried [this link](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DeveloperTips) to create firefox profile with preferences but I didnt get any result out of it.

Please share your idea or any work around. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **selenium-standalone-server-2.15.0**

In this version they make the loggers as default. So that you can find logs on your editor(Eclipse) console itself.

Comment: How can i export it to a text file?